# Appropriate data structure for social networks

Tags: python, database, graph

For a college project I am currently crawling some social networks to perform some data analysis on the datasets afterwards.

Now that my crawlers work (more or less), I am wondering what the best way to store the data is. I am crawling personal information from profiles as well as the network graph as a whole to be able to perform network analysis.

First I thought I could just save the data in a regular database. But, since I have to save the friends of every profile as well and the number of friends varies from a couple of friends to 5,000, I thought about saving everything in a database using ORM (e.g. SQLAlchemy), which would lead to redundant connections between profiles though. Another idea was to save normal profile data (interests, number of friends, city, age etc.) in a regular database and save the network graph in a separate data structure, e.g. in a NetworkX graph, or just using a network graph database for everything.

What kind of database should I use for crawling social networks? Is there any standard way of saving such data?

Comment: Why would using an ORM result in redundant (friend?) connections?